# R - Bayes Trees with more covariates than observations

Tags: r, tree, random-forest, bayesian

I receive error messages in `R` that I can't trace back.

I am trying to fit Bayesian tree models to data with more covariates than observations.
With my level of knowledge, I believed this should not be a problem, however, no matter what package I try, all attempts resulted in errors.

When using the `bcf()`-function from the `bcf`-package with `ncol(x) > nrow(x)`, I get the error:

> bcfoverparRcppClean(yscale[perm], z[perm], t(x_c[perm, ]), t(x_m[perm,  : drmu failed

`bcfoverparRcppClean()` itself is written in `C++` which I did not attempt to dig into just yet.

When I only select parts of the covariates, the function performs as expected.

Similar happens for example with the `bart()`-function from the `BayesTree`-package.
Here, the error reads:

> NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 7)

Needless to say, that there are no NAs, nor infinite values in the data and the error disappears once more observations than covariates are being fed.

Please find a reproducible example below:

```
library('stats')
library('purrr')

x <- matrix(data = rnorm(100*200), nrow = 100, ncol = 200)
y <- rowSums(x)
d <- as.numeric(rbernoulli(100, p = .5))
pihat <- 1/(1+exp(-y))


library('bcf')

bcf(y, d, x, x, pihat, nburn = 1000, nsim = 500)


library('BayesTree')

bart(x.train = x, y.train = y, ndpost = 1000, nskip = 500, usequants = TRUE)
```

I guess this must be intended behaviour since it occurs with both approaches but I can't find a conceptual reason for it.

In [Hahn, Murray, and Carvalho (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09523), the fitted trees seem to differ from conventional ones only in the prior inducing a posterior distribution, that guides the stochastic search of the model.
I believe this should not alter the ability to work with high-dimensional data, but the functions don't work as seen in the examples.

Am I missing something here? Would appreciate if someone could nudge me to the reason for this or could even come up with a work-around (as long as I am not mistaken with the theory).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone comes along that question with a similar problem.

I ended up using the `bartMachine()`-function from the `bartMachine`-package.

It can handle high-dimensional data.

Still interested in the reason why it did not work with the other packages if someone knows.